# Embedded google calendar not showing up in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, google-calendar-api

After moving my webpage to PHP 7 server google calendar not showing up in Firefox anymore. [Take a look](http://www.kylavilla.ee/) yourself (below the header, in rightside box).

i post the embedded code also.

```
 <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;height=200&amp;wkst=2&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=kylavilla8%40gmail.com&amp;color=%23182C57&amp;ctz=Europe%2FTallinn" style="border-width:0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tested this with multiple browser? Browser details will also be useful. Please provide any possible resources which can help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't browser issue. This issue come form google calendar setting. You need to setting your google calendar in public view then user will see your google calendar. Otherwise user need **SignIn** with a google account. Please follow the instruction.

**Step 1: Embed a calendar on your website**

1. On a computer, open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/). You can only get the code to embed in your website from a computer, not the Google Calendar app.
2. In the top right, click Settings Settings and then **Settings**.
3. Click the **Calendars** tab.
4. Click the name of the calendar you want to embed.
5. In the "Embed This Calendar" section, copy the iframe code displayed.
6. Open your website editor, then paste this code where you want the calendar to display.

Your embedded calendar will only be visible to people you've shared it with. To allow all visitors to see your calendar, you'll need to [make it public](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083).

**Step 2: Customize your embedded calendar**

1. On a computer, open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/). You can only get the code to embed in your website from a computer, not the Google Calendar app.
2. In the top right, click Settings Settings and then Settings.
3. Click the Calendars tab.
4. Click the name of the calendar you want to embed.
5. In the "Embed This Calendar" section, click Customize the color, size, and other options.
6. Choose your options, then copy the HTML code displayed.
7. Open your website editor, then paste this code where you want the calendar to display.

**Let site visitors save a calendar event**

You can add a Google Calendar button to your website so visitors can quickly save your event on their own Google Calendars. To let anyone to save your calendar event, you'll need to make [your calendar public](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083).

1. On a computer, open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/). You can only make changes to your calendar visibility from a computer, not the mobile app.
2. Open an event on your public calendar, then find the **"Visibility"** section.
3. Click **Publish event**.
4. In the Publish event window, copy the HTML code displayed.
5. Open your website editor, then paste this code where you want the event button to display.

**[More details](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)**.

Note: You need to read **[How public calendars work](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083)**

Thanks.